# Windows Phone Emulator Won't Boot

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, blend, microsoft-expression

I am install my pc windows phone 7.1 sdk and Microsoft Expression Blender 4 and after running my project windows phone emulator is not booting it's shows message always like "**Windows Phone Emulator is doing a complete OS boot...**". i am waiting many hours shows timeout exception.

my emulator always shows like below image:

[image]

Help me how to fix this issue!
Thanks For Reading My Post and Spend Your Valuable Time!

Comment: Do you run the emlator inside a VM? This is officially not supported and results in your problem description.

Comment: I am not run a Emulator inside VM!

Comment: Where did you get the installation file and on what OS are you? Do you have any other Windows SDK installed? Have you tried uninstalling the Windows Phone SDK and reinstall again? It is quite hard to give an answer to your problem. You should try to install the SDK from here: https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk Please provide more info if the problem still persists.

Comment: i am tried repair and reinstall same problem will be occurs doesn't boot os on windows phone emulator!

Comment: can u provide any link for windows phone emulator setup only where download?

Comment: What operating system are you running on? Have you installed the 7.1.1 SDK Refresh?